# MVC Routing - third level not showing in menu or breadcrumb

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, breadcrumbs, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using Routing attribute and MvcSiteMapper. All is well until I reach the third level:

```
[Route("productmaingroup", Name = "ProductMainGroup")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Title 1", ParentKey = "home", Key = "ProductMainGroup", Order = 1)]
http://mysite.co.uk/myrouteprefix/productmaingroup
Home > Title 1

[Route("productsubgroup", Name = "ProductSubGroup")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Title 2", ParentKey = "ProductMainGroup", Key = "ProductSubGroup")]
http://mysite.co.uk/myrouteprefix/productsubgroup
Home > Title 1 > Title 2

[Route("product/{id:int}", Name = "Product")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Title 3", ParentKey = "ProductSubGroup", Key = "Product")]
http://mysite.co.uk/myrouteprefix/product/1234
NONE?!
```

I have tried to display what happenes above in regards to the url and the breadcrumb. Have I reached a limit on sitemapper?

Comment: check your RouteConfig.cs file and make sure that the configuration is ok there

Answer (score 1):

I worked this one out for anyone who has the same problem. It is the parameter that is breaking it. Add a preservedrouteparameter in the node:

```
[Route("product/{id:int}", Name = "Product")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Title 3", ParentKey = "ProductSubGroup", 
    Key = "Product", PreservedRouteParameters = "productID")]
```